# How to declare a class already defined in static library?

Tags: c++

I am linking a static library, which encapsulate implementation of  `class A`.

```
class A
{
    private:
        B* _hal;
        int id;
    public:
        A();
        bool Open();
}
```

This class and it's `.cpp` are compiled to `.o` which are later part of the generated static library `libTony.a`. The constructor initializes `id = 1023` and allocates memory for `B* _hal`.

I am creating a header `libTony.h` which provides only declarations (I hope)

```
class A
{
    public:
        A();
        bool Open();
}
```

---

And in `main.cpp`

```
#include "libTony.h"

int main()
{
    A* o = new A();
    o->Open();
    return 0;
}
```

If I step with GDB, the program is correctly stepping inside `A()` and in `Open()` which are found in `libTony.a`.

If I `p/x this` it shows the same address in `A()` and in `Open()` (meaning its the same object), if I `p/x this->id` in `Open()` it prints the value that was assigned to `id` in `A()`. Only problem is with `_hal` which I allocated memory for in `A()` and after allocation I see it's valid, but I print its address in `Open()` it shows `0xa` which is not valid address obviously, whereas in `A()` the address is

[image]

Same address of *this, same id, but the pointer somehow got lost?  I guess the problem is in this line

`A* o = new A()`, the construction of A is correct, but the assignment is not doing what I am expecting it to do, probably the script is seeing the definition of `A` in `libTony.h`? I guess it's redefining instead of just declaring?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have a library which defines a specific class, then there should be a header file for the class that you should include. You should *never* try to redefine the class, unless you can do an exact character by character copy (otherwise you will have *undefined behavior*).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I feared this. I was hoping to give a cleaner header.

Comment: There are ways to hide implementation details (lookup the Pimpl idiom for instace). But the way you went about it is simply a violation of the ODR. The UB is not by accident. There is no binary compatibility between the way the library sees the object and the way client code lays it out according to your header.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I understand. I will make sure I read [Plmpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl). :)

Comment: Right now, your class as you redefined it has no members. I think you mix up class declarations and interfaces in your head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining `A` as a full class in the lib, but then hiding methods within it via the header file is going to lead to undefined behavior if you are not careful.

Let's do this right with interfaces.

`class A` inherits from `InterfaceA`. Put this in `libTony.h`

```
#pragma once

class InterfaceA
{
public
    virtual bool Open() = 0;
    virtual ~InterfaceA() = default; // or just "virtual ~InterfaceA() {}"
};

InterfaceA* CreateInstanceOfA();
```

Then in your CPP file, declare class A as this:

```
class A : public InterfaceA
{
    private:
        B* _hal;
        int id;
    public:
        A();
        bool Open() override;
};
```

Along with the helper function defined

```
InterfaceA* CreateInstanceOfA()
{
     A* ptrA = new A();
     return ptrA();
}
```

Then your main can be this:

```
#include "libTony.h"

int main()
{
    InterfaceA* o = CreateInstanceOfA();
    o->Open();
    delete o;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems like one of the alternatives to Plmpl `pure abstract class (OOP factory): users obtain a unique pointer to a lightweight or abstract base class, the implementation details are in the derived class that overrides its virtual member functions` I like it.